# How to dynamically add a scheduled task to Celery beat

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, celerybeat

Using Celery ver.3.1.23, I am trying to dynamically add a scheduled task to celery beat. I have one celery worker and one celery beat instance running.

Triggering a standard celery task y running task.delay() works ok. When I define a scheduled periodic task as a setting in configuration, celery beat runs it.

However what I need is to be able to add a task that runs at specified crontab at runtime. After adding a task to persistent scheduler, celery beat doesn't seem to detect the newly added new task. I can see that the celery-schedule file does have an entry with new task.

Code:

```
scheduler = PersistentScheduler(app=current_app, schedule_filename='celerybeat-schedule')
scheduler.add(name="adder",
          task="app.tasks.add",
          schedule=crontab(minute='*/1'),
          args=(1,2))
scheduler.close()
```

When I run:

```
print(scheduler.schedule)
```

I get:

```
{'celery.backend_cleanup': <Entry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup() <crontab: 0 4 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>,
'adder': <Entry: adder app.tasks.add(1, 2) <crontab: */1 * * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>}
```

​

Note that app.tasks.add has the `@celery.task` decorator.

Answer (score 1):

Celery beat stores all the periodically scheduled tasks in the  **PeriodicTask**  table. A task can be scheduled in [several ways](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#models), including crontab, interval, etc.

In order to dynamically add a scheduled task, create the desired type of schedule object (`CrontabSchedule` in the example below), and pass it into a new `PeriodicTask` object.

```
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, CrontabSchedule

# -- Inside the function you want to add task dynamically 

schedule = CrontabSchedule.objects.create(minute='*/1')
PeriodicTask.objects.create(name='adder',
                                   task='apps.task.add', crontab=schedule)
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. This was exactly what I needed and does what the OP was asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find a good workaround, I suggest you switch to the [Celery Redbeat](https://github.com/sibson/redbeat).

Comment: This looks great, but it has a small caveat: you have to use Redis.

Comment: RedBeat is not only solving the problem of having dynamic schedules, but it is trying to solve a bigger problem - high availability and reliability.

Answer (score -1):

You may solve your problem by enabling [autoreloading](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#autoreloading).

However I'm not 100% sure it will work for your config file but it should if is in the CELERY_IMPORTS paths.

Hoverer note that this feature is experimental and to don't be used in production.

If you really want to have dynamic celerybeat scheduling you can always use [another scheduler like the django-celery one](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes) to manage periodic tasks on db via a django admin.

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK autoreloading would need to be an option in celery beat, and beat doesn't support autoreload. Yes I do really want to have dynamic scheduling, and I don't use django. Looks like I am ahead of my times, and dynamic task scheduling will be supported in Celery ver 4.0

Comment: Anyway a restart of your celery-beat shouldn't be that costly especially if you have a dedicated worker that does only scheduling.

Comment: I can't restart celery-beat each time a client submits a request that may require adding new schedule. Besides, how would you do this programatically ? Btw. I've switched to python-crontab.

Comment: In your use case it's clear that configuration based scheduling is not the proper approach just write your own scheduler with a db as backend or use one of the many out there like this https://github.com/kongluoxing/celerybeatredis.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having a similar problem and a solution I thought about is to pre-define some generic periodic tasks (every 1s, every 5mins, etc) and then have them getting, from DB, a list of function to be executed.
Every time you want to add a new task you just add an entry in your DB.