# Django Celery: create periodic task at runtime with schedule depending on user input

Tags: python, django, cron, celery, runtime

I have a simple Django (v3.1) app where I receive data from a form, process it with a view and then pass it on to Celery (v4.4.7, RabbitMQ as broker). Depending on the data submitted in the form, it can be a one-time task or a periodic task.

The periodic task should execute the same task as the one-time task, but, well, with a periodic schedule. I would like to pass that schedule to the task, including a start date, end date and an intervall (e.g.: execute every 2 days at 4pm, starting now until 4 weeks).

My view (shortened and renamed for illustration purposes, of course):

```py
# views.py

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BackupForm(request.POST)
        
    if form.is_valid():
        data = ...

        if not form.cleaned_data['periodic']: 
            # execute one-time task 
            celery_task = single_task.delay(data)

        else:
            schedule = {
                'first_backup': form.cleaned_data['first_backup'],
                'last_backup': form.cleaned_data['last_backup'],
                'intervall_every': form.cleaned_data['intervall_every'],
                'intervall_unit': form.cleaned_data['intervall_unit'],
                'intervall_time': form.cleaned_data['intervall_time'],
            }

            # execute periodic task, depending on the schedule submitted in the form
            celery_task = single_task.delay(data, schedule=schedule)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:index'))
```

The single task looks like this:

```py
# tasks.py

@shared_task
def single_task(data: dict, **kwargs) -> None:
    asyncio.run(bulk_screen(data=data))
    # TODO: receive schedule if periodic and create a periodic task with it
```

This works well for the single task. However, I don't know how to adapt this to create dynamic periodic tasks. My schedule data varies, depending on the users' form input. I have to create the periodic task at runtime.

According to the [official documentation on periodic tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), **crontab schedules** is what I need:

```py
from celery.schedules import crontab

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    'add-every-monday-morning': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        'args': (16, 16),
    },
}
```

Although this looks fine, this sits in the celery config with hardcoded schedules.

I also read about the `on_after_finalize.connect` decorator where I could do something like this:

```py
@celery_app.on_after_finalize.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, task123.s('hello'))
```

But I don't know how to pass the schedule to this function. Also, what is the sender? Can I pass it from my view?

Then I read about populating the relevant models in celery beat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58062594/2179266). But I guess there has to be a more elegant way, using the stable version without deprecated decorators.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try [celery-redbeat](https://redbeat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely try populating the `PeriodicTask` or `CrontabSchedule` provided with the `django_celery_beat` package.[link to docs](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Celery beat is the scheduler which runs periodically and it will simply execute all the tasks based on a schedule (a database backed one in case of `django_celery_beat`). [Reference1](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#beat-scheduler),  [Reference2](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes)

Celery beat is certainly the cleanest way to handle periodic tasks with different schedules instead of creating your own scheduler or handle different schedules.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in celery 4.x you cannot set up the dynamic schedule you require (I recall seeing talk of it appearing in 5 but not sure if it has). Your code looks promising, however — you just need to check for a schedule in `single_task` and schedule a new task (if required) with a `countdown` or `eta`. **The task can schedule its own task(s) for a future time**.

e.g.

```
@shared_task
def single_task(data: dict, **kwargs) -> None:
    asyncio.run(bulk_screen(data=data))
    schedule = kwargs.get("schedule")
    if schedule:  # do we need to run this again?
        next_run_at = get_next_run_at(schedule)
        if next_run_at:
            # yes!
            single_task.apply_async(args=[data], kwargs=kwargs, eta=next_run_at)
        # else the task will complete without rescheduling itself

def next_run_at_schedule(schedule: dict) -> Optional[datetime]:
    """ return None if the schedule has expired, or is invalid
        else return the date and time to run the next task
    """
    pass
```

See [Celery Docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.4.7/userguide/calling.html) for `apply_async` and `eta` details. I haven't tested this but the principle is sound. You should

- add error handling within `single_task` so that subsequent runs are scheduled in the event of an error within the main code
- possibly add extra checks before doing the main task to ensure you are not running a zombie task (e.g. user has unsubscribed etc)
- DEFINITELY ensure that the user input driving the schedule has been thoroughly validated — not just that the dates are dates etc. "Never trust user input"

If you prefer, you can use `countdown` rather than `eta` with apply_async.

Of course, it may be easier (and more reliable, as correctly performing the error handling I mentioned is not trivial) to load the schedules into a database and then run a simple celery task every minute to check for backups that need to happen — this would then fire them off in parallel via `simple_task.delay(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge when building service for uptime monitoring. I wrote an article showing my approach for [dynamic periodic tasks in Celery](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/dynamically-update-periodic-tasks-celery/) and created an example project (available in [GitHub](https://github.com/saasitive/dynamically-update-periodic-tasks)).

There is [django-celery-beat](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat) package that provides database models for `IntervalSchedule` and `PeriodicTask`. You will need to add a model that will store the information about interval and period. The model should have one-to-one relationship with `PeriodicTask`:

```py
from django.db import models
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask

class ModelWithTask(models.Model):
 
    interval = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    period = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    task = models.OneToOneField(
        PeriodicTask, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

You need to create `task` object when you create `ModelWithTask` object. Then you can manipulate periodic tasks as you want. For example, at the end of the task execution just check if the `period` time is over.